# Why is an airplane propeller so different from a boat propeller in shape?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, aerodynamics

Examples:
Airplane propeller [image: 1]

Source:http://www.sensenich.com

Boat propeller [image: 2]
Source:http://www.nauticexpo.com

It is obvious that the airplane propeller is drastically different from the boat propeller in shape. At first glance the former has very narrow blades while the latter has much wider ones. Moreover, the blades of the airplane propeller all taper to rather sharp tips, which is a VERY striking contrast to those of the boat propeller.

So why the difference? What are the physical reasons accounting for this striking contrast? Does it mainly result from the difference between the weight of the air and that of the water?

Comment: Additional factors -- power required to spin fast enough to generate power and the effect of weight on getting into the air vs floating on the water.

Comment: @tpg2114 So in order to hold the plane in air an airplane propeller spins much faster than a boat one does?

Comment: Density, viscosity, Reynolds number, ...

Comment: Cavitation is also a big factor

Comment: Related? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61105/could-some-design-of-a-propeller-be-used-in-both-air-and-water

Comment: I'm not sure I believe that other answer. This is just a comment because I don't really know. I can only point out that they are both rotary wings, and the lift/drag ratio of a wing is better if it has higher aspect ratio - long and narrow. Another factor is cavitation - water propellers cannot have too large of a pressure difference, to minimize steam bubbles, so they might have to make up for it with area. But I don't really know.

Comment: ...Compressibility?

Comment: Airplane propellors and ship propellors have somewhat different functions. Airplane propellors need to move a lot of low-density mass (i.e., air) *fast*. Obviously, an airplane can't go any faster than the speed at which its propellors are moving the air. Ships are slow-moving, so a ship propellor doesn't need to move the water that quickly. However, since ships tend to be very heavy, the propellor needs to move a lot of water mass to move the ship forward. The wide blades of a ship propellor are good at moving a lot of mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Draft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8907/why-are-there-so-many-different-propeller-shapes/8909#8909) and [cavitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavitation).

Ships cannot afford to have big propeller diameters, they have to make do with the smallest diameter available in order to stay within the draft of the ships' hull. They operate in a medium which is 800 times denser than air, and one important concern is to avoid cavitation. This again means to limit suction peaks and leads to very high blade chords. The high blade count and chord results in a very large activity ratio so the pressure forces have enough area to act upon to generate the desired thrust.

Compare a ship's propeller to that of submarines: Here the single blades are more slender and the propeller looks like a cross between a ship's and an airplane's propeller (see the picture below for an example).

[image: Submarine propeller]

Submarine propeller. Its mounting position on the centerline gives it more space for a bigger diameter. Minimum draft is not a concern, so the propeller blades are less stubby. Their sweep distributes the cutting through the wake of the rudders over time, which helps a lot to reduce noise.